# Outside Bounds of Array When Reading From File

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C# - I've got a 'Treasure Hunt' game here - it hides a 't' in a box, then the user inputs coordinates - if they get 't' it says they've won, if not then a 'm' is displayed.

I'm trying to setup save games linked to the name a user enters. It writes the save game to a txt file and stores it - that much works. But when I try to load the game I keep getting an error 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'.

```
  static string username = "";
    static string saveGame = "";
    public const int BoardSize = 10;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[,] Board = new char[10, 10];
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Start New Game");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Load Game");
        Console.WriteLine("9 Quit.");
        int mainMenuChoice = 0;
        mainMenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (mainMenuChoice == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
            username = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (mainMenuChoice == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What was your username?");
            username = Console.ReadLine();
            saveGame = username + ".txt";
            LoadGame(saveGame, ref Board);
        }
        else if (mainMenuChoice == 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Closing in 3 seconds.");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        Random randomOneX = new Random();
        randomOneX = new Random(randomOneX.Next(0, 10));
        int randomX = randomOneX.Next(0, BoardSize);
        randomOneX = new Random(randomOneX.Next(0, 10));
        int randomY = randomOneX.Next(0, BoardSize);
        //Console.Write(randomX);
        //Console.Write(randomY);
        for (int i = 0; i < Board.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Board.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                Board[i, j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        Board[randomX, randomY] = 'x';
            PrintBoard(Board);
            int Row = 0;
            int Column = 0;
            bool wonGame = false;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("I've hidden a 't' in a map - you're job is to find the coordinates that have the 't' in.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a Row: ");
                bool validRow = false;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Row = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        validRow = true;
                        if (Row >= 10 || Row < 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number between 0-9: ");
                            validRow = false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ooops, you've entered something that simply cannot be, please retry.");
                    }
                } while (validRow == false);

                Console.Write("Now enter a column: ");
                bool validColumn = false;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Column = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        validColumn = true;
                        if (Column >= 10 || Column < 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number between 0-9: ");
                            validColumn = false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ooops, you've entered something that simply cannot be, please retry.");
                    }
                } while (validColumn == false);

                if (Board[Row, Column] != 'x')
                {
                    Board[Row, Column] = 'm';
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You've missed the target! Feel free to retry.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    wonGame = false;
                    PrintBoard(Board);
                SaveGame(username, ref Board);
                }
                else
                {
                    Board[Row, Column] = 't';
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("You've won!");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

                wonGame = true;
                }
            } while (wonGame == false);
        PrintBoard(Board);
            Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintBoard(char[,] Board)
    {

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The map looks like this: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(" ");
        for (int Column = 0; Column < BoardSize; Column++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + Column + "  ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int Row = 0; Row < BoardSize; Row++)
        {
            Console.Write(Row + " ");
            for (int Column = 0; Column < BoardSize; Column++)
            {
                if (Board[Row, Column] == '-')
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else if (Board[Row, Column] == 'x')
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(Board[Row, Column]);
                }
                if (Column != BoardSize)
                {
                    Console.Write(" | ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static void SaveGame(string username, ref char [,] inBoard)
    {
        StreamWriter sGame = null;
        string saveFilePath = username + ".txt";
        try
        {
            sGame = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ooops there seems to be an error with saving your game. Check the log for details.");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inBoard.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < inBoard.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                sGame.Write(inBoard[i, j]);
            }
            sGame.WriteLine("");
        }
        sGame.Close();
    }

    private static void LoadGame(string GameFile, ref char[,] Board)
    {
        StreamReader saveGameReader = null;
        string Line = "";
        try
        {
            saveGameReader = new StreamReader(GameFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            StreamWriter errorMessage = new StreamWriter("ErrorLog.txt", true);
            errorMessage.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "Error: " + e.ToString());
            errorMessage.Close();
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error loading game, check log for info. (Press Enter to exit.)");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        char[,] loadedBoard = Board;

        for (int Row = 0; Row < BoardSize; Row++)
        {
            Line = saveGameReader.ReadLine();
            for (int Column = 0; Column < BoardSize; Column++)
            {
                loadedBoard[Row, Column] = Line[Column];
            }
        }
        Board = loadedBoard;
        saveGameReader.Close();
    }
}
```

}

The link to a notepad screenshot is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7trO.jpg

Comment: The problem shows up in this line
                    loadedBoard[Row, Column] = Line[Column];

Comment: You don't need to pass the Board array with _ref_

Comment: Where do you define BoardSize? @Prasadtelkikar, he is using index to read line because it's a char array, you can access the char from a string using the index.

Comment: @Magnetron I defined it just above the static void main -  `      public const int BoardSize = 10;
`

Comment: @Steve What do you mean? I've used 'ref Board' twice in the code - and I've tried removing the 'ref' in both passes but it's given me an error.

Comment: He means you don't need ref for it to work, but that's not the error. Can you post an example save file in full above?

Comment: @captainjamie I had to post an imgur link because wherever I entered it, the spaces just didn't count.

Comment: You should try to reduce this to a [mcve]. It doesn't help that you haven't shown a stack trace either. Have you debugged through the code, and looked at the data at the point where the exception was thrown?

Comment: @Steve I'll update the code with the full everything.

Comment: (I'd also advise you to start following .NET naming conventions. Giving local variables capitalized names looks very odd.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I will do that once I get a better grasp on C#, as I said I'm new - and so my code doesn't look nice to anyone else but once I get more comfortable I'll do whatever I can to minimise the code and make it more verifiable.

Comment: @vK31RON: Don't wait - start getting into good habits and learning about diagnostics *now*. It will save you countless hours. Learn how to use the debugger, write tests etc. Hint: look at `Line` in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GetUpperBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns, as MSDN says

> Gets the index of the last element of the specified dimension in the
>   array.

So you are getting 9 everywhere you use that method. To fix your code you need to change your loops in the saving and initialization of the Board array with <= as exit condition from the loops

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Board.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= Board.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        Board[i, j] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Or keep the '<' and use `GetLength(0)` and `GetLength(1)`

Comment: Yes, or else have two constants defined for the number of rows and columns and use them to initialize the array.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue of the 'Out of bounds'. But now I have another problem of the places of the m's not being shown. Ah, nevermind I'll work it out - thanks for that though :)

Answer (score 0):

If your values in the file are like below

> m m m m m m m m X m m m
>
> m m m m m X m m X m m m
>
> m m m X m m m m X m m m

Then you can try with this approach

```
int i = 0;  
// Read the file and work it line by line.  
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(gameFile); 
foreach(string line in lines) 
    {  
    string[] columns = line.Split(' '); 
    for(int j = 0; j < columns.Length; j++)
        {
         loadedBoarder[i, j] = columns[j];
        }
        i++;  
    }
```

@captainjamie : Thanks for correcting my code.

Comment: Even `File.ReadAllLines(GameFile)` would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Your save has 9 rows but your board size was defined as 10

Comment: You're saying that there's a problem with the way in which the program is saving the board - and therefore causing issue when loading the board?

Comment: There's problems all over your code which I'd be happy to help you with in a separate area, but the exception is because you're 'expecting' 10 lines and the imgur link you posted shows 9